# My PC desktop suddenly turned off when I play games.. No warning or message, monitor just turned into blacknd PC just stop and power light blinking

Tags: shutdown

Please help me!! This is my spec..
CPU Intel pentium dual core.
Ram 2 GB ddr3.
Gpu Amd radeon 4350.I bought this PC just about a year 7 month ago and it run perfectly until yesterday... I play dota 2 on this PC for a long periods.. I turned on this PC about 8 hours than I shut down to rest the PC about 2 hour. Than I turn on to play ggames again ..and about 7 hours .about that time this PC be so laggy at games. I wonder that I have to shut down the PC but I just annoy the lagg.. And about aa next 1 hour. The PC suddenly turn off and just light at power button blinking. I just think it need to rest. Than next 2 hour I try to turn on the PC. But it nothing happen when I push the power. Just a light blinking and the PC just like no power. Than I try to switch off the switch an turn on back. The light is gone but no sign of power.. Like my PC has dead. Please tell me what too do. I have search the internet about this issues but I found nothing! Please help.. Soory because my English suck.

Comment: I am afraid your Mother board is burnt. I once had a similar experience, It was a 10 day old laptop, 4Gb ram with Ok graphics card. Was playing 3D games everyday with it and it got burnt out. Went to service centre and changed a new mother board.

Comment: @user3437460 97.5% of the time that's not how that works

Comment: I don't have money to change motherboard. Because I have 2 pc , I just recently upgraded my other PC this year. Yup, I thinks it overheating. I has looked at the motherboard but it look just normal,no part was like burnt out.

Comment: The thing it the PC can't start up at all.. When push the power it was nothing happen. No sound, no fan are spin. And no light. It just like no power on the mobo.

Comment: Maybe overheated PSU. To be honest if you want to be playing games like that you going to have to get a better computer or try and upgrade. If you read the minimum requirements for 'dota 2' it states you need 4GB of ram. Not having enough of something can start stressing out other components... http://store.steampowered.com/app/570/

Comment: Ok , next time I will upgrade the ram and change better case fan. Ty for your help but what are you guys suggest me to do? Buy new PSU?

Comment: Could be the power supply too.

Comment: Hi, the problem still have. But I has looked every inchi at the motherboard and cable.. I realise that one of the USB cable of the case that tide together with other cable..is melting. What I mean is the cable that I tide is melt. Maybe the PSU is very hot and had damage.?

Comment: Ok, 5 years late, but that is definitely a bad PSU, resulting from an overcurrent USB device/malfCable. Replace PSU, and hope it did not spike powe when failing and fry your motherboard/cpu. But odds are, clearing the short and replacing psu would have fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your pc is overheating. The reason you can play for a bit is because your not overloading the power source. 2gb probably isn't enough RAM to play a game + run your OS. Considering Windows usually uses 1.5 to 2gb alo e

Check the event log, and goto the Windows > system tab. It'll tell you what's wrong.

Comment: unexpected shutdowns are not logged.

Comment: How can he check the log without being able switch on the pc?